# If a sequence of uniformly integrable random variables converges in distribution, the sequence of corresponding expectation values converges too

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let

- Let $\operatorname{P}$ be a probability measure
- $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathcal{L}^1(\operatorname{P})$ be uniformly integrable and converge in distribution to $X$

Since $$\varphi_h(x):=\min\left\{\max\left\{-h,x\right\},h\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb{R}$$ is continuous and bounded, for all $h\in\mathbb{N}$, the *portemanteau theorem* implies $$\operatorname{E}\left[\varphi_h(X_n)\right]\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\operatorname{E}\left[\varphi_h(X)\right]\tag{1}$$ Moreover, we've got $$\varphi_h(|x|)\stackrel{h\to\infty}{\uparrow}|x|\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{2}$$ The *lemma of Fatou* yields $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{E}\left[|X_n|\right]\ge\operatorname{E}\left[\liminf_{n\to\infty}|X_n|\right]\tag{3}$$

---

I want to show that it holds $$\operatorname{E}\left[|X|\right]\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{E}\left[|X_n|\right]\tag{4}$$ and thereby $$\operatorname{E}\left[X\right]=\lim_{h\to\infty}\operatorname{E}\left[\varphi_h(X)\right]\tag{5}$$

---

Starting from $(3)$ we should be able to prove $(4)$ and $(5)$ using $(1)$ and $(2)$. However, I can't figure out how exactly I need to proceed.

Comment: The sequence $(X_n)$ converges in distribution to $X$ hence there exists some copies $X'_n$ and $X'$ of $X_n$ and $X$ such that $X'_n\to X'$ almost surely. Now, $(X'_n)$ is uniformly integrable since uniform integrability depends only on distributions, and the same for expectations, hence you are done.

Comment: @Did What do you mean by *copies*?

Comment: Same distribution.

Comment: Can you prove that? Anyway, can you deduce $(4)$ and $(5)$ from $(1)$-$(3)$?

Comment: No, and for a good reason: (3) is much too weak to get anything useful from it. Imagine that $(X_n)$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli with $P(X_n=0)=P(X_n=1)=1/2$ for every $n$ then $\liminf X_n=0$ almost surely hence (3) reads $\liminf1/2\geqslant0$ while (4) reads $\liminf1/2\geqslant1/2$.

Comment: $(3)$ itself might be too weak. But what about the other preconditions? $(4)$ and $(5)$ should be provable from $(1)$ and $(2)$ using the lemma of Fatou (maybe in some other way than I did).